# Why are there multiple profiles being displayed on the same page?

Tags: php, mysql

In my profile page for my users, I have set up a profile image system and when multiple users are logged in, the site displays all of the profile pictures on one page, rather than the individual image for the individual session  can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

PROFILE.PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbh.php';
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Yahbang</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header class="header_profile">
    <nav>
        <ul>

        </ul>
    </nav>
    <form class="logout" action='include/logout.inc.php'>
        <button>Log out</button>
        </form>
</header>

<?php


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $email = $row['email'];
        $sqlImg = "SELECT * FROM profileImg WHERE email='$email'";
        $resultImg = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlImg);
        while ($rowImg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultImg)) {
            echo "<div class='userProfileImage'>";               
                if ($rowImg['status'] == 0 ) {
                    echo "<img src='images/profile".$id.".jpg'>";
                } else {
                    echo "<img src='images/profile_default.jpg'>";
                }
                echo "<p>".$row['first']."</p>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }   
}       else {
            echo "There are no users yet!";
        }



    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        echo "<form action='include/uploadProfile.inc.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file' name='file'>
<button type='submit' name='submit'>UPLOAD</button>
    </form>";
    } else {
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }
?>






<footer class="footer_profile">
    <nav>
        <ul>

        </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tell us clearly what should be happening and what you mean by "when multiple users are logged in", on the same machine? Also you should have `exit`s after your `header` calls.

Comment: You loop over all users with the first SQL statement, the second SQL statement uses each email you've retrieved in the first statement and then the while loop creates an image for each row retrieved of the second query. Basically, you're retrieving every user, then looping over every user and getting their email, then getting the image for each one of those users

Comment: It lists all profiles because that's how you wrote your script. You should query the user table based on the id stored in the session (and use join to get the image, not a separate query).

Comment: Also, you're opening yourself up to SQL injection. Please look into using stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your profile page URL look something like this?

profilepage.php?id=5

If not, you might want to add that, because then you could easily edit your first query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
```

and do something like

```
$id= $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='$id'";
```

You can continue using that logic throughout the rest of the profile, otherwise, you'll be looping through ALL from your user table.

Comment: thanks much for this. its so helpful when im just learning to code and someone posts what would better and explains why. thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Take care at your SQL command

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
```

Add an `LIMIT 0,1` at the end like `$sql = "SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 0,1";` than you get only the first result.
If you write your SQL so you could specify your result:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE `id`='$id' LIMIT 0,1";
```

Take a look at the SQL statement